# converting date fr to timestamps

Tags: javascript, php, html

hello everybody i need a little help

my php code should take the input from "date d'ajout" in my form 
and i want tp convert it to a timestamps beacause i want to send it to my bdd.

html code

```
<p><label>Date d'ajout</label> : <input type="text" id="date_ajout" placeholder="JJ/MM/YYYY" /></p>
```

my php code

```
$date = trim($_POST["date_ajout"]);
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $date);
    return $dt->getTimestamp();
```

can you help me

sorry for my english i'm french :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post data are send by name nor id attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="date_ajout" name="date_ajout" placeholder="JJ/MM/YYYY" />
```

As long as you are not passing hour and minute details, change signature for `createFromFormat`

```
 $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
```